# How to register a servlet in AEM

Tags: aem

I'm new to AEM and I want to create an AEM servlet like this:

```
@SlingServlet(Path ={"/bin/test01"}, method={"Get"})
public class TestServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doGet(@NotNull SlingHttpServletRequest request, @NotNull SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.getWriter().write("Hello World");
  }
}
```

I tried to test it by sending a get request in POSTMAN "http://localhost:4502/bin/test01", POSTMAN shows 404 Not Found. What should I do?

I found people saying the servlet needs to be registered before it works in CRXDE, how should I do it? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have resolved the issue but just trying to explain the difference. explaining here;

you did not made any mistake only thing is you have used SCR annotation and that is old implementation which not well support on OSGI r6 release.

```
@SlingServlet(  resourceTypes = "sling/servlet/default",
                                methods = {"POST", "GET"},
                                selectors = "demoServlet",
                                extensions = "json")
```

OSGI Release 6 officially support DS(Declarative Services) annotation which is looks like below

```
@Component(service = Servlet.class,
                               property = {
                "sling.servlet.methods=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_GET,
                "sling.servlet.methods=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_POST,
                "sling.servlet.resourceTypes=" + "sling/servlet/default",
                "sling.servlet.selectors=" + "servletDemo",
                "sling.servlet.extensions=" + "json"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I used @Component and @SlingServletPaths annotation instead of @SlingServlet, after I run maven-install, I can access this servlet.